# add second angular module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, ecmascript-6

**I can't get the header component to register as a module**.

I'm stuck, trying to add a [new module](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module). I'm using the [gulp-angular-scaffold](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular). When running Unit tests (Jasmine), the 'header' module is not defined.

It seems like I'm missing a module declaration, but I'm not sure of where or why?

Thanks in advance

**folder structure snapshot:**

```
├──  app/
│   │   ├──  components/
│   │   │   └──  header/
│   │   │   │   ├──  header.controller.js
|   |   |   |   ├──  header.directive.js
|   |   |   |   ├──  header.spec.js
|   |   |   |   ├──  header.js
|   |   |   |   ├──  header.less
│   │   │   │   └──  header.html
│   │   ├──  main/
│   │   │   ├──  main.controller.js
│   │   │   ├──  main.controller.spec.js
│   │   │   └──  main.html
│   │   └──  index.js
```

**index.js:(loads the base/only successful module)**

```
angular.module('styleguide', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
```

**header.js:**

```
'use strict';

import HeaderCtrl from 'header.controller.js';

import HeaderNav from 'header.directive.js';

angular.module('header', ['styleguide'])
    .controller('HeaderCtrl', HeaderCtrl)
    .directive('HeaderDir', HeaderNav)
    .config();
```

**header.controller.js**

```
'use strict';

class HeaderCtrl {
  constructor ($scope) {
    $scope.Project = 'header.controller';
  }
}

HeaderCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

export default HeaderCtrl;
```

**header.directive.js**

```
'use strict';

class HeaderNav {

  constructor(){
      return {
        templateUrl: '../components/header/header.html'
      };
  }

}

export default HeaderNav;
```

Comment: What do `header.controller.js` and `header.directive.js` look like? Are there any syntax errors in those files?

Comment: @Tom I added the directive and controller to the post, JSHint isn't complaining about anything in the files and nothing stands out immediately to me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the module in your index file - index.js :

```
angular.module('styleguide', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'header'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
```

PS: ... unless that's not what you want ?

Comment: When I add the module that way I'm getting this error:                         `Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module header due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined`

Comment: I think its how I wrote the directive, my es6 skills are to blame there